# Interacting with android app running on emulator

Tags: android, automation, mobile, emulator

I just bought a little robot, maybe you've heard about it, it's Cozmo. I would like to run a python app on it when I plug it into my raspbery.
First I have to activate SDK mode.

To do this, my android emulator, on my raspbery, must connect to the cozmo wifi and launch the application and interact with it to start the sdk mode.

I'm looking to a software to interract with the emulator and the app.

If you have already had to do this kind of actions, what software do you recommend?

Thanks !